# Specify where Qt looks for OpenSSL DLLs

Tags: c++, qt, dll, manifest

I'm developing a software which uses QSslSocket to establish secured connections with a remote server. All DLL's I use (including Qt's precompiled DLLs) are stored into "DLL" subfolder.
I planned to put "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" into that DLL subfolder. Therefore, I copied the files and updated my manifest file accordingly.

```
<file name="libeay32.dll"/>
<file name="ssleay32.dll"/>
```

For some reason I can't explain, my application still finds "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" somewhere else, and won't work because those are the wrong version.

If I put those DLL directly into the application directory, it works, but that's not what I want to do.

EDIT: For some reason, it works for others DLL (for instance OpenCV that I use as well).

EDIT2: This is NOT duplicate with the topic @rubenvb mentioned, it is actually a bug that has been reported to Qt:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59071

How can I tell Qt to take those DLL from the folder I expect?

Comment: Duplicate is not applicable here. I edited to mention that, but the DLL subfolder already exists, with a DLL.manifest file into it. It already contains quite a few DLLs, which are for sure loaded from this place (if I rename them, I get SxS error).

Comment: I found what I was looking for. Qt loads OpenSSL through QSystemLibrary::load, which mimics Windows' behavior regarding DLL load sequence BUT doesn't take any Manifest into account. See here: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/plugin/qsystemlibrary.cpp.html

Comment: @user3606329 Finally found that it is a known Qt bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59071
I'd like to elaborate a clean answer for this question, but it's impossible, as "duplicate"...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add your `DLL` subdir to the dll search path that windows uses. You can achieve this using [SetDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx), which specifies a custom directory that windows searches for dlls.

If you had multiple directories containing the DLLs, you'd use [AddDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: It won't work, as those DLL are already loaded when entering the main function, thus at the point I can call SetDllDirectory.